# I need to toast message like the user is existing in db. where to write the code.?

Tags: android, sqlite

my code is

```
// Getting single contact
Contact Get_Contact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
        KEY_NAME, KEY_PASSWORD, KEY_CONFIRMPASSWORD }, KEY_ID + "=?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
    // return contact
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return contact;
}
```

I used this code.when i insert the existing record again, it is not inserting.Which is i expected result.But i need to toast message like "this is existing user". Where to write the code for toast/??
my Add_update_user.java file contains,

```
        if(name.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmpassword.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }
        if(!password.equals(confirmpassword))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            // Save the Data in Database
            dbHandler.Add_Contact(name,password,confirmpassword);
            //DatabaseHandler.Add_Contact(Contact contact);         
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this...

just retrieve your string Name

```
    String Contactname = cursor.getString(1);
```

after that check with your name string

```
   if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(Contactname))
    {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is existing user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
    }
```

Comment: I tried to write this code like,String Contactname = cursor.getString(1);if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(Contactname)){         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is existing user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();return;}}else{dbHandler.Add_Contact(name,password,confirmpassword);Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
here cursor can not be resolved. I could access the cursor from DBHelper class. Now i am getting confuse that where to write the code    String Contactname = cursor.getString(1);

Answer (score 1):

You can create another method passing the name to verify if the contact exists. And if you want you can also use this method later to get the contact by the name.

```
Contact Get_Contact(String name) {
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

     Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
          KEY_NAME, KEY_PASSWORD, KEY_CONFIRMPASSWORD }, KEY_NAME + "=?",
          new String[] { name }, null, null, null, null);
     if (cursor != null)
          cursor.moveToFirst();

     Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
     cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
     cursor.close();
     db.close();

     return contact;
}
```

In your activity you can verify if it's to null to check if the contact already exists:

```
if(dbHandler.Get_Contact(name) != null){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The contact already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I got the solution by,    Contact d = dbHandler.Get_Contacts(name);    if(d!= null)
  {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The contact already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } "Thanks for giving glue.."

Comment: By, i have created one method is, Get_Contacts(name). So i got it easily.